# can this decimal number be converted into a fraction?

Tags: number-theory

Can 
$$
  0.45647456647456664745666647456666647456666664745666666647456666666647\dots 
$$ 
be converted into a fraction of $\frac{N}{M}$ where $N$ and $M$ are integers? I know there is an algorithm that can convert decimal numbers with repeating digit:
$$
  0.\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_n} = \frac{(a_1a_2...a_n)}{10^n-1}
$$ 
What about for the number I gave?

Comment: It looks like it's nonrepeating and nonterminating thus it is irrational.

Comment: @Bye_World Soooo I cant convert it into a fraction?

Comment: Nope.  Sorry.  You can get arbitrarily close though.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh okay, thank you.

Comment: The number can be written in terms of the Jacobi theta functions, as $2/3$ plus some rational multiple of $\vartheta_2(0;\sqrt{10})/\sqrt[8]{10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the decimal is infinite and has no repeating pattern, it is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

As said, since there is no repeating pattern, the number cannot be expressed as a rational fraction.

However, for some applications, this could be done up to a certain level of accuracy generating the rational number with smallest denominator that lies within $dx$ of $x$. If we define $x$ as your number and $dx=10^{-n}$, we should obtain $$S(25)=\frac{1728551685965}{3786742598421}$$ $$S(50)=\frac{2520674705477721363986048}{5522048522758530448873891}$$